# Cannot get parent of Bootstrap popover in Firefox after it is hidden

Tags: javascript

I'm using a Bootstrap popover to display some options to a user, and based on the user's actions, I want to update a field in the same row as the popover was created.

To create the popover:

```
    $('a.popoverUpdateValue').on('focus', function() {
        var i = this
        $.ajax({
            url: $(i).data('link'),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: true,
            success: function(data){
                $(i).popover({
                    placement: 'top',
                    content: 'some content',
                    html: true
                }).popover('show')
            }
        });
     });
```

To close all open popovers:

```
    $('a.popoverUpdateValue').on('blur',function() {
        $('.popover:visible').popover('hide');
    });
```

To update the field I want to catch the 'click' event and use the target (which should be a button on the popover) to access its closest parent of a certain class. Like so:

```
    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.hasAttribute('button-on-popover')) {
            var action = e.target.getAttribute('my-action');
            var target = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'some url',
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    if (action == 'update'){
                        // Replace icon
                        var mytd = $(e.target).closest('td.updateAvailable');
                        mytd.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
                    }

                    // Lower number of updates in DOM
                    var num_updates = parseInt($('#num_updates').text());
                    $('#num_updates').text(num_updates - 1);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
                if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    $(this).popover('hide');
                }    
            });
        }
    });

});
```

The error happens in the if condition "if (action == 'update')" because mytd is not found, which only fails in Firefox while it works fine in Chrome. It seems to me that this happens because in Firefox, the popover doesn't have a parent.

Is it possible that a popover could lose its parent when it is hidden?  But why only in one of the two browsers?

Note: I have removed some sensitive information from the code, but hope it is understandable nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem seems to be that in Firefox, the parent-child relationship seems to have gotten lost at some point during the ajax call.  I was able to solve the problem by getting the parent before the ajax call is made, like this (see the line starting with "var updateAvailableTd = ..."):

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.hasAttribute('button-on-popover')) {
        var action = e.target.getAttribute('my-action');
        var target = $(this);
        var updateAvailableTd = e.target.closest('td.updateAvailable');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'some url',
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                if (action == 'update'){
                    // Replace icon
                    $(updateAvailableTd).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
                }

                // Lower number of updates in DOM
                var num_updates = parseInt($('#num_updates').text());
                $('#num_updates').text(num_updates - 1);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
            if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            }    
        });
    }
});
```